# WPF Progressbar style text

Tags: wpf, binding, progress-bar, controltemplate

I have a style for a progressbar that shows some text only on the PART_Indicator section:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="200">
                        <Border Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="15" Background="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
                        <Border Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="15" Background="#CEAC2D" BorderBrush="#CEAC2D"  BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <Viewbox>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" FontFamily="Times" Foreground="Black" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                           Text="{Binding ProgressText}"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have a few bars and each one should show a different kind of text (50%, 2/8, etc..) and that of course is handled by the VM.

My question is how to use this style for all the bars but differentiate only that textblock text. I presume the binding is not correct .. I probably need a TemplateBinding, but to what property?

Comment: Ordinarily you'd use Content for that kind of thing, but ProgressBar isn't a ContentControl subclass. Try Tag: `<ProgressBar Tag="{BInding WhateverProp}" />`, and in the controltemplate, `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" />`. If you want it to be less ad-hoc, you could write an attached property that would do the same thing as `Tag`, but with a descriptive name.

Comment: Thanks. That worked!